# ASP.NET EF Core Connection Problem in Async Tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading

I created a log service for asp.net. Inherently, Inherently, I'm want to, use asynchronously funcs of log service. So... I coded a MVC function as example in below.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

        private IChiefLogService _logger;

        public HomeController(IChiefLogService logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }


        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            _logger.Log("Write Database Error Message").ConfigureAwait(false);

            return View();
        }
}
```

This code part's working successfully but ef core is throwing different exceptions each request.

[first req picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjaP7.png)

[second req picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bl1t.png)

[third req picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0nwp.png)

[last req picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJv9f.png)

I think the problem is caused by ef core db connection closing when it exits the action scope in controller. What do you think is this solution? Do you have any alternative suggestions?

Comment: try adding `await`, i.e. `await _logger.Log("Write Database Error Message").ConfigureAwait(false);` (note: the compiler should already have been screaming at you that an `async` method was lacking `await` operators, aka CS1998)

Comment: yes its working but not async. the user should not wait for logging.

Comment: I think you have a huge misunderstanding about what "async" means. If you want to log something in the background, that's fine, but that is a **completely different topic** to "async". If you do something async: you await it. As simple as that.

Comment: You know there's a lot of great logging libraries like [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) and [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/) out there. Why create your own? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: thanks I will research those tools